# Directly navigate to next screen without button using sms_autofill package

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I'm new in flutter, i'm using **sms_autofill** package to listen otp from my phone.

My question is how to directly navigate to the next screen when otp already filled without making a button ?

Here's my otp screen

[image]

Really appreciate for your help, Thanks before...

Answer (score 1):

From the docs i see 2 callbacks you can use. Navigate inside one of the callbacks (prefer onCodeSubmitted)

```
onCodeSubmitted: //code submitted callback
onCodeChanged: // check if the length is your code length and do the validation
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man..and how to catch the error if i'm inserting the wrong code  ? In this case, i'm using verify button. Should i use another package ?. Sorry i forgot to ask this, do me your biggest favor ,please...

Comment: I don't know how your project is structured. I guess you have do verify it in your backend

Comment: I want to edit this answer, but it shows 'the edit queue is full at the moment', how long it takes ?, how if i send my code to your emaill ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **onCodeSubmitted** and **onCodeChanged** Like the example
[image: Example]

```
  _navigate(code) {
    /* if the code is succ.
  Navigate here
   */
  }
```